# How to insert errorbars in multiple axis plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

everyone!

I am plotting some data that need multiple y axis using `twinx`, like this:

```
def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
ax.set_frame_on(True)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)
for sp in ax.spines.values():
    sp.set_visible(False) 
fig, host = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()
par3 = host.twinx()

par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
par3.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.4))
make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
make_patch_spines_invisible(par3)
par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)
par3.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

p1, = host.plot(x, y, data=data)
p2, = par1.plot(x, w, data=data)
p3, = par2.plot(x, z, data=data)
p4, = par3.plot(x, v, data=data)

lines = [p1, p2, p3]

plt.show()
```

However I need to add error bars in my line points. I've tried to change the `plt.plot` to `plt.errorbar` so I could use the `yerr` argument, but it returns

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of linking to external sources

Comment: Referring to the `matplotlib` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html), x, y have to be scalar or array-like, and `yerr` scalar or array-like, shape(N,) or shape(2,N). So you want to check if the types of these are indeed what they have to be.

Comment: @Sameeresque all of them are array-like variables.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by removing the commas in front of the variables (they came with the original code) in this part

```
p1, = host.plot(x, y, data=data)
p2, = par1.plot(x, w, data=data)
p3, = par2.plot(x, z, data=data)
p4, = par3.plot(x, v, data=data)
```

After this, the `plt.errobar` worked fine.